# Toggle requestAnimationFrame on/off by a windows event for a class object

Tags: javascript

How do you properly toggle `requestAnimationFrame` on and off inside a windows event for a class object?

In my (just a simple demonstration) example, I want to toggle `requestAnimationFrame` on when it has scrolled within a range let's say 1000-2000px height and when the scroll goes outside of that range it turns off to save on performance.

Currently, it's not working properly in my code. The `requestAnimationFrame` seems to sometimes continue even when it has exited the range and for some reason, the browser slows down too.

I assume it has something to do with the scope and the bindings within the class.

**Code**

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.updateAnim = this.updateAnim.bind(this);
    this.updateScroll = this.updateScroll.bind(this);
    this.animID = null;
  }

  updateAnim() {
    // do stuff
    console.log("update anim");

    // continue loop
    this.animID = requestAnimationFrame(this.updateAnim);
  }

  updateScroll() {
    console.log("scrolling");

    if (window.scrollY > 1000 && window.scrollY < 2000) {
      // turn on anim
      this.animID = requestAnimationFrame(this.updateAnim);
      console.log("anim on");
    } else {
      // turn off anim
      cancelAnimationFrame(this.animID);
      console.log("anim off");
    }
  }

  init() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.updateScroll);
  }
}
```

**To run in console**

```
let c = new MyClass();
c.init();
```

**Full Code in HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        height: 4000px;
      }

      .region {
        margin-top: 1000px;
        height: 1000px;
        background-color: coral;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="region"></div>

    <script>
      class MyClass {
        constructor() {
          this.updateAnim = this.updateAnim.bind(this);
          this.updateScroll = this.updateScroll.bind(this);
          this.animID = null;
        }

        updateAnim() {
          // do stuff
          console.log("update anim");

          // continue loop
          this.animID = requestAnimationFrame(this.updateAnim);
        }

        updateScroll() {
          console.log("scrolling");

          if (window.scrollY > 1000 && window.scrollY < 2000) {
            // turn on anim
            this.animID = requestAnimationFrame(this.updateAnim);
            console.log("anim on");
          } else {
            // turn off anim
            cancelAnimationFrame(this.animID);
            console.log("anim off");
          }
        }

        init() {
          window.addEventListener("scroll", this.updateScroll);
        }
      }

      let c = new MyClass();
      c.init();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of looking at the distance you travel via scroll I would just either `debounce` or `throttle` your function if you'd like to be careful with performance.

Comment: Looking at both `debounce` and `throttle`, both seem to require a specified time delay. For my example, the `requestAnimationFrame` is supposed to run indefinitely until it exits the region. It's primarily driven by the scroll trigger that turns it on/off. The performance issue is odd in my case as something else seems to be happening that's causing the browser to slowdown even with `console.log`. Maybe multiple instances of `updateAnim` are being created in the background! Running the updateAnim indefinitely without toggling it doesn't cause a slow down as my code is just simple calculations.

Comment: Yeah in that case it's not the right thing to use. I thought I comment it in-case you are only worried about performance. This case seems like a good usage for intersection observers btw